# Prevent Android Studio Flutter app from closing after taking a picture

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am busy developing a APP On Android Studio using the Flutter framework, that functions as follows,

The user can press press a button and it will take a picture without opening the camera view.

I have a MethodChannel between my Dart/Flutter and Android.Java ,I am able to press the button and the app takes a pic and saves it to gallery.

The issue I am having is that it closes the app afterwards with no error.
Could you please have a look at my code and see if you can help me.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        new MethodCallHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {


            if(call.method.equals("test"))
            {

                StartCameraFrontCamera();

            }

            else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        });
  }



  public void StartCameraFrontCamera()
   {
      File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PicturesTest/");

      if (!directory.exists()) {
         directory.mkdir();
      }

      try {
            ReleaseCamera();

            mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }


         Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
         parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
         mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
         SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(this);
         SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
         imageName = "fontcamera.jpg";

      try{
           //mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
             mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
           //mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
             mCamera.startPreview();
             mCamera.takePicture(null,null,photoCallback);
           //mCamera.stopPreview();
           }catch(IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }

      Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

      try {
           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
           File myDir = new File(root + "/PicturesTest");
           File file = new File (myDir, "image1.jpg");
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           out.write(data);
           out.flush();
           out.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

     } catch (Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
  finish();

  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that the finish(); there is right? Did you tried to remove it?

Comment: Indeed, the call  to finish() will close the FlutterActivity and end the application.